# Linear Morphism of Schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $U$ be an arbitrary scheme and we consider the schematic fiber product $\mathbb{A}^1 _U = \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$.

My question referer to Bosch's "linear morphisms"  (of schemes) $\psi: \mathbb{A}^1 _U \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U$ as desecribed below.

If we firstly recall the case of vecor bundles $V$ over base $B$ then the morphisms are locally linear on trivialisations $V \vert_{p^{-1}(U_i)} \cong \mathbb{K}^n \times U_i$

via $\phi_{ij}: \mathbb{K}^n \times U_i \cap U_j \to \mathbb{K}^n \times U_i \cap U_j$, $(v, u) \mapsto (A_{ij}(u)v, u)$ with linear $A_{ij}(u)$.

For trivial bundles $V \cong \mathbb{K}^n \times B$ we set $U_i =B$.

MY QUESTION:

In Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" (see pages 428/ 429) there was suggested an attempt to "transfer" this formalism to schemes by do following (see below why this construction doesn't convince me). Here the excerpt:

[image]

We define a morphism $\psi: \mathbb{A}^1 _U \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U $ via

$$(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x)$$

for a section $\eta \in \mathcal{O}_U(U)$, $t \in \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}, x \in U$.

Below it is explained how $\psi$ is defined on level of rings (=local sections) namely as a map of ringed spaces we have by definition for an open affine subset $Spec(R)= V \subset U$ the description as ring map

$$\psi^{\#} _{\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V}: R[\zeta]=\mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V) \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V)$$

$$\zeta \mapsto (\eta \vert _{Spec(R)}) \cdot \zeta$$

Take into account that $\mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V)= \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} ) \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} R = R[\zeta]$.

So on level of local sections the definition of $\psi$ is clear. 
WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND is how to interpret $(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x) \in \mathbb{A}^1 _U = \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$ on level of Specs. Indeed, $t \in \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}, x \in U$. What is $\eta(x) \cdot t$? Namely what is here the product operation "$\cdot$"?

Set theoretically since $\mathbb{A}^1 _U = \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$ the $\eta(x) \cdot t$ lives in first factor $\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}$.

So mathematically the object with the "multiplication"/action $\eta(x) \cdot t$ doesn't make any sense to me.

Could anybody explain the meaning of it? Is $(\eta(x) \cdot t, x) $ just a symbolical notation?

Comment: The universal property  of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is that that there is a section $t\in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A}^1)$, the "coordinate", such that for every scheme $V$ and for every global section $\tau$ of $\mathcal{O}_V(V)$ there exists a unique morphism from $V$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ that pulls back $t$ to $\tau$.  Given a global section $\eta$ of $\mathcal{O}_U(U)$,  both the pullback of $\eta$ and the pullback of $t$ to $U\times \mathbb{A}^1$ are global sections, whose product, $\eta\cdot t$, is also a global section on $U\times \mathbb{A}^1$.  This defines a morphism to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: yes the pullback you mean in your comment is the map between global sections in light of the identification $Hom(\mathbb{Z}[t],\mathcal{O}_V(V))= Hom(V, \mathbb{A}^1)$ uniquely determine a morphism by image of $t$,right?. Indeed the notation/assignment $(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x) $ describes a map $\psi: \mathbb{A}^1 _U \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U$ in a unique way. My question is more if it is a abuse of notation or a formally neat notation (which still unclear to me).

Comment: @JasonStarr: So if I understood this notation correctly then set theoretically it is a kind of "mixed tuple" in the sense that the map $\psi$ given by $(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x) $ is a map between $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A}^1) \times U= \mathbb{Z}[t] \times U$ and $(\coprod_{x \in U}\kappa(x)[t]) \times U$ since the only "multiplication" I see here is the ring multiplication. Or is my description a completely wrong approach?

Comment: My understanding of the notation is via the universal property of affine space $\mathbb{A}^1$.  Since affine space represents the functor $V\mapsto \mathcal{O}_V(V)$, and since this functor takes values in rings, there is automatically a product structure as noted by Bosch.  I believe that his notation is intended to convey precisely that.  However, it would probably be best to ask Bosch directly, or at least to ask one other mathematician.